# Cognos BI and Active Directory Global Catalog

Tags: active-directory, cognos-bi

I've got AD forest with 2 domains, users and groups are separated to different domains (users in first, groups and other resources in second). And if you want to use AD in a such way you have to connect via 3268 port (global catalog). But I ran into a problem that the CognosBI does not work in this configuration. Is there ways to make these products work together in such a configuration?

```
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0146 The namespace 'nsname' is not available.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'Configure' failed.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'ActiveDirectoryAuthConfigure' failed.
[ ERROR ] CCL_ASSERT(supportedDomain);
[ ERROR ] src/ActiveDirectoryProviderHelpers.cpp(2552): CCLAssertError: CCL_RETHROW: 
[ ERROR ] src/ActiveDirectoryProviderHelpers.cpp(4099): CCLAssertError: CCL_THROW:
```

Comment: What is the error/phenomenon that you see?

Comment: [ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0146 The namespace 'nsname' is not available.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'Configure' failed.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'ActiveDirectoryAuthConfigure' failed.
[ ERROR ] CCL_ASSERT(supportedDomain);
[ ERROR ] src/ActiveDirectoryProviderHelpers.cpp(2552): CCLAssertError: CCL_RETHROW: 
[ ERROR ] src/ActiveDirectoryProviderHelpers.cpp(4099): CCLAssertError: CCL_THROW:

Comment: Also in InfoCenter said "You cannot connect to the Active Directory Global Catalog, which is a caching server for Active Directory Server. If the connection uses port 3268, you must change it. By default, Active Directory Server uses port 389." (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.c8pp_inst.10.2.0.doc/t_inst_activedirectoryserver_process.html%23inst_ActiveDirectoryServer_process?lang=ru)

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finded solution without global catalog, works with standart 389 port with following settings:
chaseReferrals: True
multiDomainTrees: True